# AWS is assigning wrong SSL certificate to Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I'm having trouble with ssl certificate from load balancer in AWS, I have 2 differents certificates (one for production and another one for staging), I configure new Load Balancers with the staging certificate and, for some reason some of these are taking the wrong certificate. When I enter to a subdomain asociated to one of these LB the browser show me that the certificate that is trying to load is THE OTHER CERTIFICATE I have in AWS.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need explicitly assign a cert to the load balancer. Depends how are use this LB, if it's from EKS, you need add annotation to k8s service

Answer (score 0):

Late for OP, but maybe this helps somebody else.

LB Listeners in AWS can have other certificates in addition to default certificate. Open the Listener-view in AWS Console and navigate to Certificates-tab to see other certificates associated with the Listener.

The purpose of the feature is to allow serving different certificates for different domains. In case there are several certificates for a given domain, AWS might pick a wrong one from your perspective.